# Elastic search geo point query filter

Tags: php, codeigniter, elasticsearch

I am trying to use geo_point for distance but it always shows location type double not geo_point how can I set location mapped to geo_point .

Actually I have to find all records within 5km sorted.

```
 "pin" : {
             "properties" : {
             "location" : {
             "properties" : {
             "lat" : {
             "type" : "double"
             },
                 "lon" : {
                 "type" : "double"
                 }
              }
              },
                  "type" : {
                  "type" : "string"
                  }
              }
              },
```

and when I am trying searches with this query below to find result within 5km of delhi lat long :

```
 {
          "query": {
            "filtered": {
              "query": {
                "match_all": {}
              },
              "filter": {
                "pin": {
                  "distance": "5",
                  "distance_unit": "km",
                  "coordinate": {
                    "lat": 28.5402707,
                    "lon": 77.2289643
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

It shows me error query_parsing_exception and No query registered for [pin]. I cannot figure out the problem. It always throws this exception

```
  {

            "error": {
                "root_cause": [
                    {
                        "type": "query_parsing_exception",
                        "reason": "No query registered for [pin]",
                        "index": "find_index",
                        "line": 1,
                        "col": 58
                    }
                ],
                "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
                "reason": "all shards failed",
                "phase": "query",
                "grouped": true,
                "failed_shards": [
                    {
                        "shard": 0,
                        "index": "find_index",
                        "node": "DtpkEdLCSZCr8r2bTd8p5w",
                        "reason": {
                            "type": "query_parsing_exception",
                            "reason": "No query registered for [pin]",
                            "index": "find_index",
                            "line": 1,
                            "col": 58
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "status": 400

        }
```

Please help me to figure out this problem. how can I set geo_point and solve this exception error and status 400 and all_shards_failed error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to map your `pin` type like this, i.e. using the [`geo_point` data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html):

```
# 1. first delete your index
DELETE shouut_find_index

# 2. create a new one with the proper mapping
PUT shouut_find_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "search_shouut": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can index a document like this

```
PUT shouut_find_index/search_shouut/1
{ 
   "location": {
      "lat": 28.5402707,
      "lon": 77.2289643
   },
   "type": "dummy"
}
```

And finally your query can look like this

```
POST shouut_find_index/search_shouut/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "5km",
          "location": {
            "lat": 28.5402707,
            "lon": 77.2289643
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Val.... can you please help me to set type geo_point as it alwayz shows me type double not geo_point

Comment: You need to delete your index first and re-create it. See my updated answer

Comment: what i need to insert related database data before creating index or after it ??

Comment: 1) delete the index, 2) create it again with the proper mapping 3) populate it with your database data 4) query it

Comment: i got this error
 "type": "index_not_found_exception",   "reason": "no such index",

 "pin": {"properties": {"location": {
                    "type": "geo_point"
                },
                "type": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }

Comment: When performing which step ?

Comment: 4 step after populate database.... 
in 2nd step i got this
 "pin": {
"properties": {
 "location": {
                    "type": "geo_point"
                },
                "type": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
but after 3rd step i have got two pins

Comment: Can you show the query you're sending and how you're sending it?

Comment: using elastic search library... iam inserting data like this
$response = $client->index([
     'index' => 'shouut_find_index',
     'type' => 'search_shouut',
      'id' => '1',
     'body' => [
      'messageId' => '1',
         'pin' => array('location' => array( "lat"  => 28.5402707, "lon" => 77.2289643), 'type' => "dummy"),
      ],
         
     ]);

Comment: I've updated my answer to use the correct index (`shouut_find_index`) and type (`search_shouut`). Please try again.

Comment: If anyone is dumb like me and wants to save 15 minutes of headache, note that the field is called 'lon' not 'long'.